# How to get coordinates of all vertical lines using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning

How can I get the coordinates of all these vertical white lines as a list using OpenCV or any other method.

[image]

This is what i did to get these lines

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from PIL import Image 

document_img = cv2.imread("2.jpg")
table_list = [np.array(document_img, copy=True)]

for each_table in table_list:
  img = cv2.cvtColor(each_table, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
  img_height, img_width = img.shape
  thresh, img_bin = cv2.threshold(img, 180, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
  img_bin_inv = 255 - img_bin
  kernel_len_ver = max(10, img_height // 50)
  kernel_len_hor = max(10, img_width // 50)
  ver_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, kernel_len_ver))  # shape (kernel_len, 1) inverted! xD
  hor_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (kernel_len_hor, 1))  # shape (1,kernel_ken) xD
  kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))
  image_1 = cv2.erode(img_bin_inv, ver_kernel, iterations=3)
  vertical_lines = cv2.dilate(image_1, ver_kernel, iterations=4)
  cv2_imshow(vertical_lines)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import cv2

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('EdPhD.png')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply a threshold to the grayscale image
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Apply a morphological operation to close gaps in the lines
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
closed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# Find the contours in the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(closed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Initialize a list to store the coordinates of the vertical lines
vertical_lines = []

# Iterate through each contour and extract the coordinates of the bounding rectangle if it's a vertical line
for contour in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    if w < h/5:  # adjust this value based on the width of your lines
        # Append the coordinates of the vertical line to the list
        vertical_lines.append((x,y,x+w,y+h))
        
        # Draw a rectangle around the vertical line
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (0,255,0), 2)


# Print the coordinates of the vertical lines
print(vertical_lines)

# Show the image with rectangles drawn around the vertical lines
cv2.imshow('image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```